# ReactJS responsive carousel from scratch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Okay, so basically I am trying to write a carousel for ReactJS from scratch.

I've accomplished to code must of the features required as navigation, slides and so on.

The main purpose of this is to make it responsive, but that is what I am having a hard time figuring out how to do.

**carousel.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import classNames from 'classnames'

export default class Carousel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this)
      this.handlePrev = this.handlePrev.bind(this)

      this.state = {
        innerWidth: 0,
        navPrevDisabled: true
      }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      var stateItems = []

      for(let i in this.props.items) {
        stateItems.push(
          <div className="react-item movie" key={i}>
            <div className="front">
              <div className="front-image" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.items[i].poster})`}}>
              </div>
              <div className="backdrop medium">
                <div className="react-play-button fill">
                  <figure className="icon-content"></figure>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }

      this.setState({
        items: stateItems
      })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateCarousel, false)
    }

    updateCarousel = () => {
      var $reactItem = $('.carousel-wrapper .carousel-inner .react-item')
      var maxw = $('.carousel-wrapper').width()

      /*var slideItemsFit = $reactItem.filter(function () {
        return $(this).position().left < maxw
      }).length*/

      var itemsFitSlide = Math.floor(maxw / $reactItem.outerWidth(true))

      console.log(itemsFitSlide)

      var margin = $reactItem.outerWidth(true) * itemsFitSlide

      margin = (maxw - margin) / itemsFitSlide / 2

      $reactItem.css({marginLeft: `${margin}px`, marginRight: `${margin}px`})

      this.setState({
        itemsShownTotal: itemsFitSlide,
        itemWidth: $reactItem.outerWidth(true),
        navNextDisabled: (itemsFitSlide === this.state.items.length),
        itemsFitSlide: itemsFitSlide
      })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.updateCarousel()
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateCarousel, false)
    }

    handleNext(e) {
      var state = this.state
      var maxw = $('.carousel-wrapper').width()

      var innerWidth = -Math.abs(state.innerWidth - (state.itemWidth * state.itemsFitSlide))

      var itemsLeft = state.items.length - state.itemsShownTotal
      var lastSlide = state.itemsFitSlide > itemsLeft

      if(lastSlide) {
        innerWidth = -Math.abs(state.innerWidth - (state.itemWidth * itemsLeft))
      }

      var itemsShownTotal = (lastSlide)
        ? state.itemsShownTotal + itemsLeft
        : state.itemsShownTotal + state.itemsFitSlide

      this.setState({
        itemsShownTotal: itemsShownTotal,
        innerWidth: innerWidth,
        navPrevDisabled: false,
        navNextDisabled: itemsShownTotal === state.items.length
      })
    }

    handlePrev(e) {
      var state = this.state

      var innerWidth = state.innerWidth + (state.itemWidth * state.itemsFitSlide)

      //var itemsLeft = state.itemsFitSlide - state.itemsShownTotal

      var firstSlide = false
      if(innerWidth >= 0) {
        firstSlide = true
        innerWidth = 0
      }

      var itemsShownTotal = (firstSlide)
        ? state.itemsFitSlide
        : state.itemsShownTotal - state.itemsFitSlide

      this.setState({
        itemsShownTotal: itemsShownTotal,
        innerWidth: innerWidth,
        navPrevDisabled: firstSlide,
        navNextDisabled: false
      })
    }

    render() {
      var nav = {
        prev: classNames({
          navigation: true,
          prev: true,
          disabled: this.state.navPrevDisabled,
          whiteframe: true
        }),
        next: classNames({
          navigation: true,
          next: true,
          disabled: this.state.navNextDisabled,
          whiteframe: true
        })
      }
      return (
        <section className="block collection carousel portrait">
          <div className="scaffold">
            <i className={nav.prev} onClick={this.handlePrev}></i>
            <i className={nav.next} onClick={this.handleNext}></i>
            <header className="collection-header">
              <NavLink to={this.props.route}>
                <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
              </NavLink>
            </header>
            <div className="carousel-wrapper">
              <div className="carousel-inner use-transition" style={{transform: `translateX(${this.state.innerWidth}px)`}}>
                {this.state.items}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      )
    }

}
```

Basically let's say there's 5 images in a slide, but only width enough in the wrapper to fit 4 images, I then want to redo the process and margin the 4 images to fit the center of the wrapper.

**carousel.css**

```
.scaffold {
  position: relative;
}

.block.collection .collection-header {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
  .block.collection .collection-header h2 {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    color: #212d33;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
.block.collection.carousel .carousel-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.block.collection.carousel .carousel-wrapper .carousel-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
  .block.collection.carousel .carousel-wrapper .carousel-inner.use-transition {
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
  }

  .block.collection.portrait .react-item {
      width: 186px;
      margin: 0 0px 20px 0px;
  }
  .block.collection.portrait .react-item.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .block.collection .react-item {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .block.collection.portrait .react-item .front {
    height: 279px;
}

.block.collection .react-item .front {
    background-color: #212d33;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.block.collection .react-item .front .front-image {
    animation: fadein 500ms;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

.block.collection .react-item .backdrop {
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 5;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(15, 22, 26, 0.25);
}
.block.collection .react-item .backdrop:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.react-play-button.fill {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 68px;
}

.react-play-button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.react-play-button .icon-content {
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.block.collection.carousel .navigation {
  top: 49%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 66px;
  background: rgba(249, 249, 251, 0.7);
  width: 48px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
.block.collection.carousel .navigation.disabled {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.block.collection.carousel .navigation:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.block.collection.carousel .navigation:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.block.collection.carousel .navigation.prev {
  left: -25px;
}
.block.collection.carousel .navigation.next {
  right: -25px;
}

.block.collection.carousel .navigation::after {
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 24px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 18px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.block.collection.carousel .navigation.prev::after {
  left: 13px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: what is your question? have you read through this code: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

Comment: @BlairAnderson yes I've almost read through their entire package, and tried to use it, but their responsive settings failed to work with the breakpoint, therefore I'd rather try to do it myself.

Well the question is, how do I make it responsive?

Comment: You will need a react library to look at media queries, and then add media queries to your configuration.

Comment: @BlairAnderson already tried just by using CSS, can't seem to get it to work. Any chance you could help me out?